# Bleachbit on ubuntu 18.04 delete rotated logs-what does this do?

Tags: bleachbit

Hi I ran bleachbit on ubuntu 18.04 using the command delete rotated logs-it says on the program that this deletes old system logs-what are these old system logs? does bleachbit delete anything important using this command?

Specifically if i did delete some log files could i break my ubuntu system? or could i make the internet browser firefox or my vpn which used openvpn unusable?

Comment: Logs are only important if you need to refer to them. If you never have, then they're not important. Many logs are *rotated* (daily, weekly, monthly) to keep them small, and old logs deleted automatically. If you look in /var/log, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Log rotation shoves the latest logs off the stage into an (optionally compressed) compressed archive file as discussed in `man logrotate`, with default settings specifying how many old logs are kept, and how often rotation happens, in /etc/logrotate.conf.  Files in /etc/logrotate.d/ hold non-default settings for specific apps and files.

Comment: would using this delete rotated logs command on bleachbit delete files needed for ubuntu to boot up/function or other files relating to internet browsers or files needed for open vpn to work?

Comment: In a word, no. Been using BleachBit with various Ubuntus for about a decade with no such problem. This seems to be your real issue, is it not? If so, please rephrase your question to include that information, by clicking [edit] underneath the question.

Comment: so just to make sure i understand this right, the bleachbit 'rotated logs' command only deletes old logs files on ubuntu, it does not erase any other files on my computer at all -can i assume all i just wrote in this comment is true then?

Comment: That is correct.